# Bluetooth applet (also Blueman) blinking in and out of existence

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth, indicator, bluetooth-speaker, blueman

OS: ubuntu 16.04 LTS

My laptop's bluetooth is winking in and out of existence, seemingly at random. I noticed at first when my bluetooth speakers turned off. Upon inspection the applet itself is disappearing, then reappearing in the top bar during these fits. They last for about ten seconds, then stabilize for a few minutes, then they wink in and out again.

I installed Blueman because some slightly similar issues were solved by it, but now I just have two applets that blink in and out at the same time, implying that there is some deeper issue.

Edit:

name@computer:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 [8086:0887] (rev c4)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 BGN [8086:4062]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp.
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 8087:07da Intel Corp.
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Comment: Investigating: Previously I managed to connect the speaker, and it would work normally for a random interval. Now the fits seem to be so regular that I can't even do that. I also got this error from Blueman:

Connection Failed: blueman.bluez.errors.DBusFailedError: Protocol not available

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

I found that blueman was blinking because I set my device to be visible for a certain amount of time, and that because the applet was updating every second to display the amount of time remaining before my device became invisible, it would blink in and out.
It stopped once I set my device to always be visible by going opening "Adaptors" and selecting "Always visible".
I hope this helps!